# Is it computable if a particular number follows the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: computability, number-theory

I was attempting to write a computer algorithm to determine if a particular number breaks the Collatz conjecture.  It is very easy to determine if a particular number falls into a loop, however I cannot think of any way to determine if a particular number is on an infinite divergent trajectory.

Assuming the Collatz conjecture is false, is it computable to determine whether or not a particular number is on an infinite trajectory?

Comment: You have edited this question to make my answer invald.  Bad form.  I deleted it, but it is still the case that our ignorance does not determine mathematical truth.  The Collatz conjecture is probably true, and so computing whether or not a number is on an infinite trajectory is probably trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: we don't know :-)

There is a ((very) little) chance that the Collatz sequence is Turing complete (with probably some caveats like in the case of [Two-counter Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine)); i.e. there is an algorithm which for every turing machine $M$ outputs an $x$ such that:

$Collatz(x)$ is on a divergent trajectory if and only if $M$ doesn't halt on empty tape

in other words "deciding if a particular Collatz trajectory is divergent" could be undecidable.

Comment: Your condition should be uniform, i.e.: "There is algorithm which for every Turing machine $M$ outputs a number $x$ such that $\mathrm{Collatz}(x)$ is divergent iff $M$ does not halt on empty tape."

Comment: @AndrejBauer: thanks, it was/is a quite informal answer (perhaps a reduction to HALT exists); however I changed it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

First, some small tips about the testing:

The following are easily shown to be equivalent: a. The Collatz sequence reaches 1 for every starting point x ≥ 1. b. The Collatz sequence reaches a value y < x for ever starting point x ≥ 2. This reduces the work a lot.

You need to make sure that large numbers in a sequence are handled correctly. For example, if you use 64 bit integer arithmetic and don't watch out, you will get integer overflow and therefore rubbish results for relatively small starting values.

Now it's easy if you are a bit careful to write code that tries to test if the Collatz sequence ends at 1, with the following possible outcomes: a. Your code proves the sequence ends. b. Your code notices that it encountered numbers too large for it to handle. c. Your code detects a cycle. d. Your code detects that it didn't reach 1 in a very large number of steps. e. Your code just continues running forever.

Case a is fine. In case b, you change your code. Case c disproves the conjecture. Case e has never been encountered by anyone. Case d has never been encountered by anyone with the right definition of "very large". If you find a number where you can't prove it reaches 1, that's when you need to worry about it - but it's likely it will never happen.